What's difference between It's nice to meet you and Nice to meet you?
In some places I heard "Nice to meet you" and in some places "It's nice to meet you".
Is there any difference between them?

The difference is that "It's" is implied and unspoken in one of them. This can be done in many situations ("Dreadful weather!" "Sick car!"), but for the learner, there's no harm in saying all the words.

Leila, you're not supposed to cross-post. So maybe delete the other one?

In greetings, it's common to leave out it's: Nice to see you, Nice to meet you, So good of you to come. Believe me, if you are in a receiving line, you'd end up leaving off the it's.

Thank you so much

Or as Bruce Forsyth would say: "to meet you nice".

There is an ellipsis in

Nice to meet you.

Omitted are the subject and verb of

(It's) nice to meet you.

The two sentences have the same meaning although the first one is informal.
Omitting Subjects and Auxiliary Verbs says

We can omit both the subject pronoun (most likely 'I' and 'you') and the auxiliary verb at the beginning of a clause when the meaning is obvious. This is very common in informal English, especially with questions. [emphasis added]


[Are you] Done with your food?

Although our case here is not a question and the subject is not I or you, it can still have this ellipsis applied.
